# Spring Boot - inject map<Enum,Class> from application.yml

Tags: initialization, yaml, spring-boot

I use spring boot in a J2SE app.

I have some constant data, such as a map, indicating a `HandlerClass` to process one operation Type.

The map relation is not changed, so I want to config it in application.yml

I try this:

```
info:
  modify_nodeip: omm.task.impl.ModifyNodeIpHandler
```

But the map is only can be recognized as `Map<String,String>`, How can I inject the map as `Map<Enum,Class>`?

Thank you!

**Updated:**
I followed @cfrick instruction, but it doen't work.

application.yml

```
config:
    optHandlerMap:
        modify_oms_nodeip: 'omm.task.opthandler.impl.ModifyOMSNodeIpHandler'
```

TestConfiguration:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "config")
public class TestConfiguration
{

    Map<OperationType,OptHandler> optHandlerMap; // here we store the handlers, same name in yaml
    TestConfiguration() {}

}
```

and the main func used the configuration

```
@Autowired
private TestConfiguration testConfiguration;
```

what's wrong with that? But it doesn't work, `optHandlerMap` in `testConfiguration` is null.

Comment: `modify_oms_nodeip:'` is most likely wrong (`:<space>'`)

Comment: I add a space after `:` but it still dosn't work :-(     Need the `ModifyOMSNodeIpHandler` be instanced? I only have a `@Component` in `ModifyOMSNodeIpHandler`.

Comment: Your original question was for `Map<Enum,Class>`.  `OptHandler` would be an instance.  Otherwise you can set the loglevel of `org.springframework.core.env` to `DEBUG` to get hopefully more insight.

Answer (score 4):

You can play a trick like this:

In your `TestConfiguration`, define a `Map<String,String>`, and getter.

then provide a `Map<Operator,Handler> getXXXX()` function, in this function, convert the `Map<String,String>` to `Map<Operator,Handler>`.

Maybe you need to use reflect to new a instance.

By the way, you can use `Maps.transform()` in Guava to perform the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

You write your own settings and annotate as `@ConfigurationProperties` (see [21.6 Typesafe Configuration Properties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties))

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="cfg") // the root in my yaml
class HandlerConfiguration {
    public enum Handler { Handler1, Handler2 } // enum 
    Map<Handler,Class> handlers // here we store the handlers, same name in yaml
    HandlerConfiguration() {}
}
```

Then my `application.yaml` looks like this:

```
cfg:
  handlers:
    Handler1: 'app.Handler1'
```

And accessing it like this:

```
def ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application, args)
ctx.getBean(HandlerConfiguration).with{
    assert handlers.size()==1 // there is the one
    assert handlers[HandlerConfiguration.Handler.Handler1] // it's key is the enum
    assert handlers[HandlerConfiguration.Handler.Handler1] == Handler1 // its value is the actual class
    handlers[HandlerConfiguration.Handler.Handler1].newInstance().run()
}
```

(`app.Handler1` is just some random class I put there, all this is in the same package (`app`))

Comment: I have tried, but It doesn't work. `config:
  optHandlerMap:
    modify_oms_nodeip:'omm.task.opthandler.impl.ModifyOMSNodeIpHandler'` the TestConfiguration:`@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "config")
public class TestConfiguration
{

    Map<OperationType,OptHandler> optHandlerMap; // here we store the handlers, same name in yaml
    TestConfiguration() {}

}` and the usage `    @Autowired
    private TestConfiguration testConfiguration;`

Comment: @NingLee you can update your test code in the question.

Comment: @NingLee a) `modify_oms_nodeip:'` is invalid yaml (`:<space>'`); b) **what** does not work... errors?  exceptions?

Comment: @cfrick I updated in the question, and I add the `space` after `:`.

Answer (score 0):

just enable config `spring.data.rest.enable-enum-translation` ([Spring document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#spring.data.rest.enable-enum-translation)) and Spring will do the trick